# Phaser event issue. Why did my change resolve it?

Tags: phaser-framework

Apologies for the title but I'm hoping somebody could explain why I was getting the below error and how come what I changed fixed it.

**Overview:**

I'm creating a game where you have to shoot 3 targets to win. If you hit all 3 a HIT state is loaded (Consequently if you don't hit all 3 a MISS state is loaded).  Once in the HIT state you click the screen which then triggers some game logic that determines if you have won a prize. The game logic is a php script that runs and returns a win or lose variable via ajax. Once returned a state change is triggered to direct you to the WIN state or LOSE state depending on the result.

All 4 state code:

**Hit State**

```
MyGame.Hit = function () {};
MyGame.Hit.prototype = {
    create: function () {
        this.bgd = this.add.image( 0, 0, 'hitBgd');
        this.bgd.inputEnabled = true;
        this.bgd.events.onInputDown.add( this.gameLogic, this);
    },
    gameLogic: function () {
        var username = 'user';      
        if (typeof username !== 'undefined') {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', '_/api/logic.php?user=' + username, true);
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
                var returnedData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                if (returnedData.outcome === true) { // Winner
                    MyGame.game.state.start('Won');                     
                } else { // Loser
                    MyGame.game.state.start('Lose');
                }
            }           
        }
        request.send();
    } else {
        MyGame.game.state.start('Lose');
    }
}       
};
```

**Miss State:**

```
MyGame.Miss = function () {};
MyGame.Miss.prototype = {   
    create: function (){
        this.bgd = this.add.image( 0, 0, 'missBgd');
        this.playAgainBtn = this.add.button((this.game.width / 2) - 145, 235, 'playAgainBtn', this.playAgain, this);
        this.exitBtn = this.add.button((this.game.width / 2) + 145, 235, 'exitGameBtn', this.exitGame, this);
    },
    playAgain: function () {
        this.state.start('MainMenu');
    },
    exitGame: function () {
        alert('AWAITING LINK FROM CLIENT');
    },
};
```

**Won State**

```
MyGame.Won = function () {};
MyGame.Won.prototype = {
    create: function () {
        this.bgd = this.add.image( 0, 0, 'wonBgd');
        this.playAgain = this.add.button(130, 510, 'wonPlayAgainBtn', this.playAgain, this);
        this.exitBtn = this.add.button(395, 510, 'wonExitGameBtn', this.exitGame, this);
    },
    playAgain: function () {
        this.state.start('MainMenu');
    },
    exitGame: function () {
        alert('AWAITING LINK FROM CLIENT');
    }       
};
```

**Lose State**

```
MyGame.Lose = function () {};
MyGame.Lose.prototype = {
    create: function (){
        this.bgd = this.add.image( 0, 0, 'loseBgd');
        this.playAgainBtn = this.add.button((this.game.width / 2) - 145, 235, 'playAgainBtn', this.playAgain, this);
        this.exitBtn = this.add.button((this.game.width / 2) + 145, 235, 'exitGameBtn', this.exitGame, this);
    },
    playAgain: function () {
        this.state.start('MainMenu');
    },
    exitGame: function () {
        alert('AWAITING LINK FROM CLIENT');
    }   
};
```

As you can see the MISS, WON and LOSE states are all the same apart from in the WON state my button is called **this.playAgain** instead of **this.playAgainBtn**. 
The first time you win is fine but if you play again without refreshing the page and get to the HIT state, trigger the game logic and win, you get the below error

```
Uncaught Error: Phaser.Signal: listener is a required param of add() and   should be a Function.
```

It then points out this.playAgain in my WON state.

I want to know why changing this to this.playAgainBtn removes the error. Should I be destroying events/signals? should I be naming my functions differently even though they are in different states/objects?
also why do I need to call MyGame.game.state.start('Won'); in the ajax request instead of this.state.start('Won'); to switch states?

When this goes live and the odds are adjusted the chance of this happening will be ridiculously slim but at the moment for development everyone is a winner.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a button called `playAgain` but the callback method is also called `playAgain`, they have the same name and that is what is causing the error.

When `MyGame.Won.create()` is called for the first time, and you add the `MyGame.Won.playAgain` button then the reference to your original callback function `MyGame.Won.playAgain()` is retained by that button. But the second time you start the Won-state `MyGame.Won.create()` is also called, and then the reference to your original callback function was lost because it was effectively overwritten by the button.

Comment: Thank you that make obvious sense now. One other question, inside my Ajax function I have to use MyGame.game.state.start('Won'); to trigger the state change instead of this.state.start('Won'); How come I can't use the latter in this instance? I'm a little confused as to what is different with this function compared to the others.

Comment: I don't know how you're triggering javascript from php, so can't answer that. But I also found variable scope and the "this" keyword in JavaScript a little tricky at first. If you want a better understanding of JavaScript I can recommend "You don't know JS": https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: All the php file does is to serve as the game logic. I have a few databases I need to pull data from before my logic is run so I trigger the php through an Ajax request and depending on the outcome, I switch the phaser game state. As this page states https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/resources/Project%20Templates/Basic/Game.js  When a State is added to Phaser it automatically has the following properties set on it, One of which is this.state.  CONTINUED

Comment: If you look at the section of code under HIT STATE you will see I have an if else statement to switch my states. I would usually use this.state .start('state to switch to') but here it only works if I make reference to the main phaser game object and call MyGame.game.state.start('state to switch to'); Thanks for the link I'll give them a read through.